# Time split in R

Tags: r, split

i have a data frame like:

```
21/05/2013
21/05/2013 00:30
21/05/2013 01:00
21/05/2013 01:30
21/05/2013 02:00
21/05/2013 02:30
21/05/2013 03:00
21/05/2013 03:30
21/05/2013 04:00
21/05/2013 04:30
```

I need to seperate date and time in different column. I have already tried

```
Date<-as.Date(DF4385$Date,"%d/%m/%Y")
datetxt <- as.Date(Date)
data.frame(date = datetxt,
day = as.numeric(format(datetxt, format = "%d")),
month = as.numeric(format(datetxt, format = "%m")),
year = as.numeric(format(datetxt, format = "%Y")))
```

but for seperating time using `%H:%M` is not working.

Comment: Why are you running `as.Date` twice? Also what do you want to do with the time component? Either way, you could split the `Date` column into parts using something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(DF4385)[, tstrsplit(Date, "/|\\s|:", type.convert = TRUE)]`.

Comment: yes it works. thank you. i just wanted to seperate date and time. i want to make a plot using them.

Comment: Hadley's package `lubridate` provides lots date functions like `year()`,`month()`.

Comment: If you only want to separate date and time, I would recommend using `setDT(DF4385)[, IDateTime(as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %R"))]`. The `itime` column will have a `ITime` class which will allow you to manipulate it.